# Javascript dropdown list not working

Tags: javascript, css

I just started learning the web development languages, and I'm trying right now to make a dropdown list using javascript (I already tried in CSS, but it didn't work).
I would appreaciate if you would tell me what's wrong in my code.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="anchors">
    <!-- This is where the dropdown list should appear if you hover your mouse over it -->
        <li class="list-comanda">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="dropdown()">Comanda</a>
        </li>  
        <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                <li class="dropdown-l-magneti"><a href="magneti"> Magneti de frigider personalizati</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-l-hartie"><a href="hartie"> Obiecte facute din hartie</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <li class="list-contact"><a href="contact">Contacteaza-ma</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script>        
    function dropdown{
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
        dropdown.style.display = "inline-block";
    }   
</script>
```

I am sincerely sorry if my code is unorganized.

Comment: Are trying to do this using only JavaScript because there is an HTML element for that?

Comment: use select tag to make a drop down. li tag is used for showing list of items

Comment: some syntax errors there replace function dropdown with function dropdown() for function declaration

Comment: `function dropdown(){...}` instead of ` function dropdown{...}`

Comment: You cant have a `div` as a child of a `ul`

Comment: Hey, you are aware that you could achieve this entirely with CSS?

Comment: You should have a look at bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this entirely in css.  First create your menu markup ensuring that you embed your drop down list inside the li's that you want, we will give them a class of `dropdown` so that we can hide them by default.

```
<ul id='menu'>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
  <li class='dropdown'>link 4
    <ul>
      <li>sublink</li>
      <li>sublink</li>
      <li>sublink</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In  our markup, you can see we have one of our child `li`s with an embedded dropdown list, we use a class here as using an id would prevent us from being able to have multiple dropdown lists on the same page (remember id's should always be unique to describe a specific portion of the content, whereas classes allow us to repeat common tasks).

We then hook up our css:

```
#menu {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu .dropdown ul {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

#menu .dropdown:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu .dropdown ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

A few things to note here, at the start we set the default styling of our drop down ul to `display: none` this completely hides it from the page.  We also use `vertical-align: top` on our menu li's to ensure that when the drop down menu shows it doesn't push the menu items down when the dropdown menu is shown (try disabling this and you'll see what I mean).  Finally we add a `hover` event to the dropdown menu using the child selector tool.  This means that we can bind the `hover` event to our `.dropdown` class and apply the styles directly to its child `ul` (which is the element that is hidden).  If we just tried to set the `.dropdown` class to `display; block` then we would not see any change.

[A jsfiddle of this example can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/ywo231ch/) there is no pretty styling on it but I'm sure you can figure that out yourself.  If you've any other questions let me know.

As an aside from the answer to this post, I'd like to note that using something like [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) is a great way of quickly implementing nicely styled and cross browser components, the above link directly applies to their drop downs.  However I'm aware you said that you are a beginner to web dev and I totally understand that you want to learn how to put this stuff together; just don't get into the habit of re-inventing the wheel, you'll soon learn that using battle tested code is sometimes the better option :)

Answer (score 0):

declare function dropdown correctly :- `function dropdown(){//body}`

Answer (score 0):

you're calling `dropdown` function `onmouseover`. where is this function?

change:

```
function dropdown{
```

to:

```
function dropdown(){
```

**[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdLndmrc/)**

Answer (score 0):

i think we need  () for a function

```
<script>

        function dropdown(){
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
            dropdown.style.display = "inline-block";
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this not be easier:

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thats a select list and not a drop down menu.